# Continuations in Java

Tags: java, continuations

Is there a good implementation of continuations in Java?

If so, what is the overhead like? The JVM wasn't designed with these sort of things in mind, right? So is this kind of going against the grain?

Comment: See also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846428/available-coroutine-libraries-in-java

Comment: See also [How are coroutines implemented in JVM langs without JVM support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033944/how-are-coroutines-implemented-in-jvm-langs-without-jvm-support)

Answer (score 13):

See Apache Javaflow http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/javaflow/

It's the only continuation package for java that's actively under development.  The other one, RIFE, I'm not sure which state it's in.

Answer (score 10):

Javaflow
 http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/javaflow/
 Play framework use Javaflow
 http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/29/play/

RIFE
 http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/continuations.html
 WebWork use.

JauVM
 http://jauvm.blogspot.com/2005/07/so-what-does-it-do.html
 JVM in JVM, implements tail call / continuation

Scala 2.8
 http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096

Cocoon
 http://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/userdocs/flow/continuations.html
 http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/RhinoWithContinuations

Jetty
 http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Continuations
 retry request.

coroutines
 http://code.google.com/p/coroutines

jconts
 https://github.com/idubrov/jconts

jyield
 http://code.google.com/p/jyield

Kilim
 http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/thread_of_ones_own.pdf

ATCT
 http://portal.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=949362

Answer (score 7):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) has [continuation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/continuations.html) support. There is further discussion and some samples at [DZone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/continuations-continue).

I can't advise on the efficiencies or otherwise, other than to say that the Mortbay team always appear concious of such issues. There will most likely be a discussion of implementation trade-offs somewhere on the Jetty site.

Comment: It seems the Jetty continuation implementation is tied up with its Servlet container, so I don't think this can help me.

Comment: Jetty continuations are not real continuations in the programming language sense.  It's just a trick to re-trigger a request processing.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, there is now a [**`CompletableFuture<T>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class which supports continuations and more functional / reactive programming approaches.

Consider the following example, where a Class offers a `downloadAndResize` method:

```
public CompletableFuture<Image> downloadAndResize(String imageUrl, int width, int height) {
    return CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> downloadImage(imageUrl))
        .thenApplyAsync(x -> resizeImage(x, width, height));
}

private Image downloadImage(String url){
    // TODO Download the image from the given url...
}

private Image resizeImage(Image source, int width, int height){
    // TODO Resize the image to w / h
}
```

Usage of the above method could look like:

```
CompletableFuture<Image> imagePromise = downloadAndResize("http://some/url", 300, 200);

imagePromise.thenAccept(image -> {
    // Gets executed when the image task has successfully completed

    // do something with the image

});
```

Comment: The question asks about continuations implementations. `CompletableFuture` is just one of possible ways to nicely wrap and use them.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, I suppose the obvious problem involves unwinding the stack with closure instances active. I suppose a language with lexical scope could in theory figure out that a child frame may create a closure instance, identify those intermediate frames that are referenced, and then it could malloc those frames instead of just pushing them on the stack.

For that matter, a compiler could malloc all frames or all parent frames of a closure referencing a non-globally-bound object.

#### Summary

I don't think the JVM restricts closures any more than a real machine, it's just that they fight the general stack paradigm and so they usually get punted.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind implicit continuations, [Kilim](https://github.com/kilim) is a great option. It works by processing annotated methods and generating the continuations in bytecode for you. Obviously it does a lot more since it's a framework, but if you want the (excellent) performance of thread-safe continuations, it's worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Play! framework version 1.2.x also has [support for continuations](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/asynchronous#Continuations) integrated with async http goodies.

Note that [Play 1.2.x continuations only work with the inbuilt Netty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228574/plays-continuations-holding-http-threads).

And [Play 2.x still has no support for continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977509/continuations-in-play-2-0).

Answer (score 1):

Another strong competitior has appeared recently.

[Quasar](http://www.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/) uses [forked](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#acknowledgments) from Matthias Mann's implementation of java [continuations](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#advanced-fibers) to provide higher level features like [lightweight threads](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#fibers), Erlang-like [actors](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#quasars-actor-system) and Go-like coroutines and [channels](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#channels).

There are many benchmarks and detailed introductions in the [Quasar Blog](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/tagged/quasar/).

There is also ready-to-use integration named [Comsat](http://www.paralleluniverse.co/comsat/) aimed to help easily building performant web services based on continuations machinery under the hood.

Quasar also provides a nice Kotlin API that was featured on recent JetBrains webinar 
[Quasar: Efficient and Elegant Fibers, Channels and Actors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nmob2MB2Qo8).

Everything mentioned is open-source and free to use.

See also http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2015/08/07/scoped-continuations/

---

**Update**

Quasar's experience was later used as foundation for the [Loom Project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/loom/) which [aims](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/Loom-Proposal.html) to bring continuations support directly into JVM sometime past Java 11.

It's under [active development](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/loom/loom/) now and already has a working alpha [prototype](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/loom-dev/2018-July/000062.html).

Answer (score 1):

Consider also [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html).

It's [implemented](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/kotlinconf2017/slides/2017+KotlinConf+-+Deep+dive+into+Coroutines+on+JVM.pdf) via potentially more performant [CPS transformations](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#continuation-passing-style) ([still stackful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021816/difference-between-thread-and-coroutine-in-kotlin#comment73195386_43023289)) and can use any async executor under the hood like ForkJoinPool or [Quasar integration](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/0.18/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-quasar).

Comes with handy [guided](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md) [library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines).

Beware of some [tooling](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-much-of-a-leaky-abstraction-coroutines-are/2370) and [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654537/how-to-run-suspend-method-via-reflection) pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) also runs on JVM. So it might be relevant.

[What are Scala continuations and why use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512930/what-are-scala-continuations-and-why-use-them)

In addition Scala has somewhat similar async/await feature:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/async.html

Answer (score 0):

Another library by Matthias Mann:

http://www.matthiasmann.de/content/view/24/26/

http://www.matthiasmann.de/java/Continuations/

Comment: A fork of this proof-of-concept library was used in much more feature-rich and mature [Quasar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37789961/603516) framework.