# Generating Java source code and jumps

Tags: java

I am generating Java code on the fly which will then be compiled and loaded back in. My issues is that I essentially need jumps because when I return from the function I wish to continue execution from the point in the loop from where I have exited. Hopefully, the code here illustrates my desire. Although the actual code will have some ifs as well and be much deeper.

```
MyIter a,b,c;

boolean func() {
 jump to correct state here

 state0:

 a = ...;
 while (a.next()) {
   state1: while (b.next()) {
     return true; // start again at state1
   }
   b = ...;
 }

 c = ...;
 state2:
 while (c.next()) {
   return true; // start again at state2
 }
 return false;
}
```

In C I would probably use a jump table and state variable. Performance is the key here and the code interacts with the Java application.

My best guesses so far have been:

- Flipping the nesting of loops and the logic. That became too cumbersome and problematic.
- Adding logic to allow the flow to get back to where it was but this may be messy.
- I assume the bytecode can jump so I could generate the bytecode myself but that doesn't seem ideal (is there any good libraries for this?)
- Continuation passing style to avoid returning but that would involve major restructuring, although currently the likely way to go.

I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts?

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time doing jumps even in bytecode - the verifier has all sorts of rules that make bytecode a lot less flexible than you might think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to use a switch block (or if you have to, nested switch statements)

```
enum State {
   state1, state2, state3;
}

State state = State.state1;

public boolean func() {
   while(true) {
     switch(state) {
        case state1:
            if(test()) return true;
            state = state2;
            break;
        case state2:
            if(test2()) return false;
            state = state3;
            break;
        case state3:
            if(test3()) return true;
            state = state1;
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After playing and thinking a little more this looks the best option for my purposes. A quick implementation is working well, although sadly it will be nested at times.

Comment: You may be able to flatten the states by having state3_1, state3_2, ... state3_N.  That may or may not make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A Java coroutine library might suit your purposes. See [this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846428/available-coroutine-libraries-in-java) for some pointers.