# Coroutines in Java

Tags: java, coroutine

I am reading this page about [coroutines in Python](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2320938) and this [Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) I saw that there are a few [libraries in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846428/available-coroutine-libraries-in-java) implementing coroutines.

My question is: is there any known reason why the Java designers decided not to implement coroutines so far and is there any plan to include it in a future version of Java?

Thanks.

Comment: What can you do with coroutines that you could not do with `Thread`s in java?

Comment: If there are libraries implementing coroutines already, what do the language designers need to do?

Comment: As I understand from the first link, it is less resource consuming than `threads`. The question is: why isn't it included in the standard Java language.

Comment: Questions like "why did the language designers do this or that" ... actually don't have a place here. Answers would be more of general; opinion-based. So, typically; such questions get you more downvotes that anything else. Nonetheless ..

Comment: The wikipedia page indicated that it could be done with threads, but that the "yield" step _could_ be implemented as a jump to the method.

Comment: @Jägermeister I think there's a lot of value in asking why a language was designed a certain way. Sometimes the answer is simply "because that's just the way it is", but I still find that to be useful knowledge when trying to learn something new.

Comment: @flkes I am not saying that such questions are all bad. But I do not think that SO is the best place to ask them. SO is about **specific** programming problems; not about language design in general.

Comment: @Jägermeister Disagree. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) directly says it's okay to ask about **software tools commonly used by programmers**. This question falls into that category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the concept of a co-routine was the **first** design of the Java threading system. The `wait`/`notify` mechanism is a simplistic form of co-routine where `notify` is equivalent to `yield` etc.

Since then much has been done, particularly to make structures thread-safe rather than algorithms. This derives from the realization that it is not the **code** that must synchronize/yield but the **data structure used to communicate between the threads** that must be thread-safe.

Comment: What you call "realization" is really a decision. There are many approaches to the issue, you should not present the one Java settled for as the only possible one.

Comment: @back2dos - please do add to my answer. I am interested in the alternative options.

Comment: No, wait/notify is just the classic OS-level mechanism to suspend and resume OS-level threads of execution, and it's preemptive. Coroutines are implemented in user-space, end hence work cooperatively rather than having the kernel arbitrates and preempts. In their stackful form, it's about performing stack manipulations to save and restore the stack and registers so you can save and then resume the execution where it was left at. After you've saved the state, you are free to jump wherever else you want to keep your actual OS-level thread of execution busy, without any OS-level intervention.

Answer (score 6):

## Project Loom

Continuations and Coroutines will come to Java in the nearer future and they’ll be called *virtual threads* (also referred to as *fibers*). There’s a [project called Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main):

> Project Loom is intended to explore, incubate and deliver Java VM features and APIs built on top of them for the purpose of supporting easy-to-use, high-throughput lightweight concurrency and new programming models on the Java platform. This is accomplished by the addition of the following constructs:
>
> - [Virtual threads](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Differences+between+regular+Threads+and+virtual+Threads)
> - Delimited continuations
> - Tail-call elimination

Further reading: [https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/Loom-Proposal.html](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/Loom-Proposal.html)

To quote that document:

> It is the goal of this project to add a public delimited continuation (or coroutine) construct to the Java platform. However, this goal is secondary to fibers …

Preliminary builds of [Project Loom are available](http://jdk.java.net/loom/) now, based on early-access Java 16.

Answer (score 3):

On the *"are there any plans ..."* part of the question, the answer is:

> Not at this stage

The JEP list (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0) does not make any mention of coroutines.  The list covers features added in Java 8, added or targeted for Java 9, or proposed for future releases.

Interestingly, there was an RFE submitted in March 2013 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029988).  The RFE only got one vote, and it was closed 9 months with the suggestion to submit a JEP.  Nobody has bothered to take the idea any further, which to me is telling.

Comment: "Nobody has bothered to take the idea any further, which to me is telling." - Just curious; telling of what? That no one in Java community wants coroutines? That Oracle isn't keen on implementing them? Or something else

Comment: It is telling me that nobody of any stature in the Java world thinks that coroutines are needed.  Because, if someone did think they were needed, someone would have initiated a JEP.  However, obviously that does not amount to a "proof".

Answer (score 2):

It's synced with Java 15 build 7.

[Link](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/loom-dev/2020-January/001002.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's an another choice is here for Java6+

A pythonic coroutine implementation:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

class CorRunRAII {
    private final List<WeakReference<? extends CorRun>> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    public CorRunRAII add(CorRun resource) {
        if (resource == null) {
            return this;
        }
        resources.add(new WeakReference<>(resource));

        return this;
    }

    public CorRunRAII addAll(List<? extends CorRun> arrayList) {
        if (arrayList == null) {
            return this;
        }
        for (CorRun corRun : arrayList) {
            add(corRun);
        }

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();

        for (WeakReference<? extends CorRun> corRunWeakReference : resources) {
            CorRun corRun = corRunWeakReference.get();
            if (corRun != null) {
                corRun.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CorRunYieldReturn<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> {
    public final AtomicReference<ReceiveType> receiveValue;
    public final LinkedBlockingDeque<AtomicReference<YieldReturnType>> yieldReturnValue;

    CorRunYieldReturn(AtomicReference<ReceiveType> receiveValue, LinkedBlockingDeque<AtomicReference<YieldReturnType>> yieldReturnValue) {
        this.receiveValue = receiveValue;
        this.yieldReturnValue = yieldReturnValue;
    }
}

interface CorRun<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> extends Runnable, Callable<YieldReturnType> {
    boolean start();
    void stop();
    void stop(final Throwable throwable);
    boolean isStarted();
    boolean isEnded();
    Throwable getError();

    ReceiveType getReceiveValue();
    void setResultForOuter(YieldReturnType resultForOuter);
    YieldReturnType getResultForOuter();

    YieldReturnType receive(ReceiveType value);
    ReceiveType yield();
    ReceiveType yield(YieldReturnType value);
    <TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> TargetYieldReturnType yieldFrom(final CorRun<TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> another);
    <TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> TargetYieldReturnType yieldFrom(final CorRun<TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> another, final TargetReceiveType value);
}

abstract class CorRunSync<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> implements CorRun<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> {

    private ReceiveType receiveValue;
    public final List<WeakReference<CorRun>> potentialChildrenCoroutineList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Outside

    private AtomicBoolean isStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private AtomicBoolean isEnded = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private Throwable error;

    private YieldReturnType resultForOuter;

    @Override
    public boolean start() {

        boolean isStarted = this.isStarted.getAndSet(true);
        if ((! isStarted)
                && (! isEnded())) {
            receive(null);
        }

        return isStarted;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        stop(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Throwable throwable) {
        isEnded.set(true);
        if (throwable != null) {
            error = throwable;
        }

        for (WeakReference<CorRun> weakReference : potentialChildrenCoroutineList) {
            CorRun child = weakReference.get();
            if (child != null) {
                child.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return isStarted.get();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnded() {
        return isEnded.get();
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getError() {
        return error;
    }

    @Override
    public ReceiveType getReceiveValue() {
        return receiveValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void setResultForOuter(YieldReturnType resultForOuter) {
        this.resultForOuter = resultForOuter;
    }

    @Override
    public YieldReturnType getResultForOuter() {
        return resultForOuter;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized YieldReturnType receive(ReceiveType value) {
        receiveValue = value;

        run();

        return getResultForOuter();
    }

    @Override
    public ReceiveType yield() {
        return yield(null);
    }

    @Override
    public ReceiveType yield(YieldReturnType value) {
        resultForOuter = value;
        return receiveValue;
    }

    @Override
    public <TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> TargetYieldReturnType yieldFrom(CorRun<TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> another) {
        return yieldFrom(another, null);
    }

    @Override
    public <TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> TargetYieldReturnType yieldFrom(CorRun<TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> another, TargetReceiveType value) {
        if (another == null || another.isEnded()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Call null or isEnded coroutine");
        }

        potentialChildrenCoroutineList.add(new WeakReference<CorRun>(another));

        synchronized (another) {
            boolean isStarted = another.start();
            boolean isJustStarting = ! isStarted;
            if (isJustStarting && another instanceof CorRunSync) {
                return another.getResultForOuter();
            }

            return another.receive(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.call();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            stop(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

abstract class CorRunThread<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> implements CorRun<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> {

    private final ExecutorService childExecutorService = newExecutorService();
    private ExecutorService executingOnExecutorService;

    private static final CorRunYieldReturn DUMMY_COR_RUN_YIELD_RETURN = new CorRunYieldReturn(new AtomicReference<>(null), new LinkedBlockingDeque<AtomicReference>());

    private final CorRun<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> self;
    public final List<WeakReference<CorRun>> potentialChildrenCoroutineList;
    private CorRunYieldReturn<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> lastCorRunYieldReturn;

    private final LinkedBlockingDeque<CorRunYieldReturn<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType>> receiveQueue;

    // Outside

    private AtomicBoolean isStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private AtomicBoolean isEnded = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private Future<YieldReturnType> future;
    private Throwable error;

    private final AtomicReference<YieldReturnType> resultForOuter = new AtomicReference<>();

    CorRunThread() {
        executingOnExecutorService = childExecutorService;

        receiveQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
        potentialChildrenCoroutineList = new ArrayList<>();

        self = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            self.call();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            stop(e);
            return;
        }

        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public abstract YieldReturnType call();

    @Override
    public boolean start() {
        return start(childExecutorService);
    }

    protected boolean start(ExecutorService executorService) {
        boolean isStarted = this.isStarted.getAndSet(true);
        if (!isStarted) {
            executingOnExecutorService = executorService;
            future = (Future<YieldReturnType>) executingOnExecutorService.submit((Runnable) self);
        }
        return isStarted;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        stop(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(final Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable != null) {
            error = throwable;
        }
        isEnded.set(true);

        returnYieldValue(null);
        // Do this for making sure the coroutine has checked isEnd() after getting a dummy value
        receiveQueue.offer(DUMMY_COR_RUN_YIELD_RETURN);

        for (WeakReference<CorRun> weakReference : potentialChildrenCoroutineList) {
            CorRun child = weakReference.get();
            if (child != null) {
                if (child instanceof CorRunThread) {
                    ((CorRunThread)child).tryStop(childExecutorService);
                }
            }
        }

        childExecutorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    protected void tryStop(ExecutorService executorService) {
        if (this.executingOnExecutorService == executorService) {
            stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnded() {
        return isEnded.get() || (
                future != null && (future.isCancelled() || future.isDone())
                );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return isStarted.get();
    }

    public Future<YieldReturnType> getFuture() {
        return future;
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getError() {
        return error;
    }

    @Override
    public void setResultForOuter(YieldReturnType resultForOuter) {
        this.resultForOuter.set(resultForOuter);
    }

    @Override
    public YieldReturnType getResultForOuter() {
        return this.resultForOuter.get();
    }

    @Override
    public YieldReturnType receive(ReceiveType value) {

        LinkedBlockingDeque<AtomicReference<YieldReturnType>> yieldReturnValue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

        offerReceiveValue(value, yieldReturnValue);

        try {
            AtomicReference<YieldReturnType> takeValue = yieldReturnValue.take();
            return takeValue == null ? null : takeValue.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ReceiveType yield() {
        return yield(null);
    }

    @Override
    public ReceiveType yield(final YieldReturnType value) {
        returnYieldValue(value);

        return getReceiveValue();
    }

    @Override
    public <TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> TargetYieldReturnType yieldFrom(final CorRun<TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> another) {
        return yieldFrom(another, null);
    }

    @Override
    public <TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> TargetYieldReturnType yieldFrom(final CorRun<TargetReceiveType, TargetYieldReturnType> another, final TargetReceiveType value) {
        if (another == null || another.isEnded()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Call null or isEnded coroutine");
        }

        boolean isStarted = false;
        potentialChildrenCoroutineList.add(new WeakReference<CorRun>(another));

        synchronized (another) {
            if (another instanceof CorRunThread) {
                isStarted = ((CorRunThread)another).start(childExecutorService);
            }
            else {
                isStarted = another.start();
            }

            boolean isJustStarting = ! isStarted;
            if (isJustStarting && another instanceof CorRunSync) {
                return another.getResultForOuter();
            }

            TargetYieldReturnType send = another.receive(value);
            return send;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ReceiveType getReceiveValue() {

        setLastCorRunYieldReturn(takeLastCorRunYieldReturn());

        return lastCorRunYieldReturn.receiveValue.get();
    }

    protected void returnYieldValue(final YieldReturnType value) {
        CorRunYieldReturn<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> corRunYieldReturn = lastCorRunYieldReturn;
        if (corRunYieldReturn != null) {
            corRunYieldReturn.yieldReturnValue.offer(new AtomicReference<>(value));
        }
    }

    protected void offerReceiveValue(final ReceiveType value, LinkedBlockingDeque<AtomicReference<YieldReturnType>> yieldReturnValue) {
        receiveQueue.offer(new CorRunYieldReturn(new AtomicReference<>(value), yieldReturnValue));
    }

    protected CorRunYieldReturn<ReceiveType, YieldReturnType> takeLastCorRunYieldReturn() {
        try {
            return receiveQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void setLastCorRunYieldReturn(CorRunYieldReturn<ReceiveType,YieldReturnType> lastCorRunYieldReturn) {
        this.lastCorRunYieldReturn = lastCorRunYieldReturn;
    }

    protected ExecutorService newExecutorService() {
        return Executors.newCachedThreadPool(getThreadFactory());
    }

    protected ThreadFactory getThreadFactory() {
        return new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(final Runnable runnable) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        if (runnable instanceof CorRun) {
                            CorRun self = (CorRun) runnable;
                            self.stop(throwable);
                            thread.interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return thread;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now you can use pythonic coroutines in this way
(e.g. fibonacci numbers)

Thread Version:

```
class Fib extends CorRunThread<Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        Integer times = getReceiveValue();
        do {
            int a = 1, b = 1;
            for (int i = 0; times != null && i < times; i++) {
                int temp = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = temp;
            }
            // A pythonic "yield", i.e., it returns `a` to the caller and waits `times` value from the next caller
            times = yield(a);
        } while (! isEnded());

        setResultForOuter(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return getResultForOuter();
    }
}

class MainRun extends CorRunThread<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String call() {

        // The fib coroutine would be recycled by its parent
        // (no requirement to call its start() and stop() manually)
        // Otherwise, if you want to share its instance and start/stop it manually,
        // please start it before being called by yieldFrom() and stop it in the end.
        Fib fib = new Fib();
        String result = "";
        Integer current;
        int times = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {

            // A pythonic "yield from", i.e., it calls fib with `i` parameter and waits for returned value as `current`
            current = yieldFrom(fib, i);

            if (fib.getError() != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(fib.getError());
            }

            if (current == null) {
                continue;
            }

            if (i > 0) {
                result += ",";
            }
            result += current;

        }

        setResultForOuter(result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Sync(non-thread) version:

```
class Fib extends CorRunSync<Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        Integer times = getReceiveValue();

        int a = 1, b = 1;
        for (int i = 0; times != null && i < times; i++) {
            int temp = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        yield(a);

        return getResultForOuter();
    }
}

class MainRun extends CorRunSync<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String call() {

        CorRun<Integer, Integer> fib = null;
        try {
            fib = new Fib();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String result = "";
        Integer current;
        int times = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {

            current = yieldFrom(fib, i);

            if (fib.getError() != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(fib.getError());
            }

            if (current == null) {
                continue;
            }

            if (i > 0) {
                result += ",";
            }
            result += current;
        }

        stop();
        setResultForOuter(result);

        if (Utils.isEmpty(result)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Execution(Both versions will work):

```
// Run the entry coroutine
MainRun mainRun = new MainRun();
mainRun.start();

// Wait for mainRun ending for 5 seconds
long startTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(!mainRun.isEnded()) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimestamp > TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wait too much time");
    }
}
// The result should be "1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55"
System.out.println(mainRun.getResultForOuter());
```

Comment: not entirely known to you what goroutines are all about...