# Multithreading using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: multithreading, jvm, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm experimenting with [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html) and have following code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    println("number of cores: $cores")

    val jobs = List(10) {
        async(CommonPool) {
            delay(100)
            println("async #$it on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
}
```

This is my output:

```
number of cores: 4
async number:0 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
async number:2 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
async number:3 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
async number:4 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
async number:5 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
async number:1 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
async number:7 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
async number:6 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
async number:9 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
async number:8 on thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
```

According to Roman Elizarov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232925/3734457) to another coroutines related question:

> "The launch just creates new coroutine, while CommonPool dispatches
>   coroutines to a ForkJoinPool.commonPool() which does use multiple
>   threads and thus executes on multiple CPUs in this example."

According to Java 8 [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html):

> "For applications that require separate or custom pools, a
>   ForkJoinPool may be constructed with a given target parallelism level;
>   by default, equal to the number of available processors."

**Why there are only 3 worker threads being used?** There are the same 3 worker threads even when I increase number of async tasks to 1000+.

My configuration:
Mac/High Sierra with dual core cpu (with [Hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), thus 4 visible cores), Kotlin 1.2, kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.19.3 and JVM 1.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of [`CommonPool`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/core/kotlinx-coroutines-core/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CommonPool.kt), you'll notice that it's working on `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool` or a thread pool with the following size:

```
(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1).coerceAtLeast(1)
```

With `4` available processors, this will result in `3` which answers why you do see 3 worker threads.

The `ForkJoinPool`-size can be determined as follows (will be the same):

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().parallelism
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53157947/8073652) if you work with coroutines version >= 1.0

Answer (score 4):

As of Coroutines 1.0, the code will look slightly different since `CommonPool` will be replaced with `Dispatchers.Default` now:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    println("number of cores: $cores")

    val jobs = List(10) {
        async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            delay(100)
            println("async #$it on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
}
```

Also, you will now get the following:

> It is backed by a shared pool of threads on JVM. By default, the maximal number of threads used by this dispatcher is equal to the number CPU cores, but is at least two.