# Kotlin coroutines vs threads

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I am currently working on an Android app written in Kotlin. I see 2 things on different places and I would like to know the difference between them. Sometimes functions are written like this:

```kotlin
fun functionThread() = thread {
   doSomeWork()
}.start()
```

So, if I understand correctly, this way, `doSomeWork()` is executed in a new thread that is created.

On the other hand, sometimes they use coroutines:

```kotlin
fun functionCoroutine() {
    CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        doSomeWork()
    }
}
```

I would like to know what is the biggest difference between these 2 approaches and what are the benefits and downfalls. I thought that nowadays coroutines are almost always a better choice than threads since they are lighter and threads are heavier for processing. Can someone please explain to me this a little bit more.

Comment: Your question is lacking context as to why either of those is used. Generally coroutines support cancellation, thread switching, suspension (awaiting for result) while writing "sequential" code (avoiding callback pattern). I can only imagine thread being useful in some cases with java interop that's not readily compatible with coroutines.

Comment: Yes thats what I think. So threads are almost "deprecated" when comparing to coroutines, right?

Comment: Not deprecated, just a lower level feature that takes more knowledge and care to use correctly. It's like how OpenGL isn't deprecated just because you can use Android Views, which are ultimately a more feature rich abstraction over it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 very nice explanation with views and abstraction example. 
I would only like to point out that using Threads without coroutines almost always gives you worse performance results (coroutines are much lighter for memory). So threads are usually second solution to use, first and best are coroutines. This was my opinion before I asked the question, I was just seeking validation from more experienced guys like you

Comment: Coroutines still use Threads under the hood. They're light weight in the sense that there's a Thread pool. If you're only doing a couple of tasks at a time, you won't see the benefits of the thread pool.

Comment: Thanks man. Your explanation is gold

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between a thread and a coroutine in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021816/difference-between-a-thread-and-a-coroutine-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

As developer (not an expert) here is what I understand from coroutines and threads.

### Thread

A thread is a sequence of statements (assignments, calculations, `if`s, `for`s, `while`s, etc.) (each corresponding to one or more CPU instructions) that are executed by CPU **one after the other**. If multiple threads are defined, their statements can run concurrently regarding each other.

In other words, when you create a thread, you say to the OS that the block of code (bunch of statements) (which is like any other ordinary code, maybe tens or thousands of lines, creating objects, calling functions, those functions calling other functions, changing variables, having loops, etc.) can be executed concurrently in respect to code that is not in the block.

So, if there are threads *t1* and *t2* and *t3*, the operating system may execute one or more of *t1* statements and then switch to execute statements in *t2* where it left off last time and then switch to execute statements in *t3* where it left off last time and then again switch to execute statements in *t1* where it left off last time and this continues indefinitely until either there is no more statements in the threads or the process is terminated.

If the CPU is multicore, then the OS may execute threads [in parallel (simultaneously) instead of concurrently (rapidly switching between them)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050222/8583692).

### Coroutine

A coroutine is exactly like a thread in that it is a sequence of statements that run one after the other in the coroutine itself, and can run concurrently in respect to statements in other coroutines (if there are any).

Coroutines are something that run on top of threads and instead of the operating system switching between them, it is the programming language runtime that switches between coroutines (operating system still switches between threads). So, if the coroutine *c1* is executing in thread *t1*, the runtime may switch to execute *c2* and then *c3* and so on while the OS has not yet switched from *t1* to *t2*.

### Comparison and the difference

The operating system keeps track of each thread by a data structure called [TCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_control_block).

The language runtime keeps track of each coroutine with a data structure called [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

Now, each thread in OS has its own stack in memory which takes several Megabytes but each coroutine continuation takes only several kilobytes.
Compare the amount of memory needed for 1000 threads vs 1000 coroutines.

Coroutines also have other benefits like they suspend and free their underlying thread to execute other code instead of blocking it. Also, they have structured concurrency (more control over their lifetime and cancellation).

I also think that switching between threads (which is done by OS) is more expensive than switching between coroutines.