# How does method in coroutine block work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Coroutine has two types. Stackful and Stackless. And Kotlin coroutine is stackless coroutine.

On the other hand, once a method gets called it is stacked on the memory. And we can do recursive calling with method.

And in Kotlin, all I need to do is adding `suspend` keyword for the methods that are called in coroutine context.

It doesn't have a stack, then how does it work?

What I am guessing is, since coroutine Object belongs to a certain thread, the thread have them. Let's say, yes it is. Then how does it work under the hood?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin coroutines are actually a hybrid between stackful and stackless. For every function invocation there is a regular Java stack frame. When you invoke a `suspend fun` from a `suspend fun`, the JVM stack grows the usual way, and if the call returns without any suspension happening, the stack unwinds also in the common JVM way.

Things become different when a function suspends. At that point, the Java methods return and the JVM stack unwinds. However, while the call chain was being built up, another, on-heap structure was being formed: a linked list of `Continuation` objects. Every `suspend fun` invocation creates another such object, which you can think of as a stack frame (it contains the values of all the local variables), but implemented at the bytecode level, as a regular Java object.

This `Continuation` chain is the "stackless" aspect of Kotlin coroutines. When you resume a continuation, you'll enter the innermost function call (containing the location where the function suspended). When that function wants to return, it won't return the normal way, instead it will resume its caller's continuation. This will repeat in the caller, and so as you travel *up* the `suspend fun` call stack, you'll be also traveling *down* the JVM call stack: the JVM stack grows as the suspendable functions return.

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for the descriptive answer. I want to dig deeper. Can you give the link to the resource that can help?

Comment: You can check out this talk of mine from KotlinConf 2017 where I show some internal implementation details with an actual example of this mechanism https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8