# What is the key difference between threads and coroutines in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, java-threads

As new to Kotlin, I am facing a little problem in understanding the difference between thread and coroutine. Can someone make it simple to understand the fundamental them of them?

I started learning core concepts of Kotlin programing language recently, but I got stuck in differentiating threads and coroutines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are native mechanisms, whereas coroutines are user-level abstractions, which use threads and actually make better use of them.

Key differences I can point out:

- Thread is a different mechanism, which is linked to the native thread
  of OS. This is the reason why creating hundreds/thousands of threads
  is impossible - thread consumes a lot of OS' memory. Coroutine is a
  **user-level abstraction** of some worker which does not use excessive
  amount of memory, since it is not linked to native resources and use
  resources of JVM heap.
- Thread gets blocked instead of suspending and dispatching the job to
  another thread.
- Thread cannot be used until its work completes.
- Coroutine is a user-friendly abstraction which allows you to reuse thread's resources to execute suspending functions. Mechanism is following: suspending function is called from a coroutine and dispatched on a specific thread. While it *suspends*, thread resources can be used to execute another suspending function.

To get better understanding of how coroutines work in combination with threads, you can read my answer to my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616946/how-the-coroutine-knows-that-it-is-time-to-resume-suspend/74630088#74630088), which is also a source for this answer.

Comment: Last bullet point could be misleading. Starting a thread or launching a coroutine are both asynchronous. The code within a thread’s `run` or a coroutine’s lambda are both synchronous. You might be conflating the terms coroutine and suspend function.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yep, I misworded that one. Thank you for pointing out