# How to handle timeouts in Retrofit inside the Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I want to show an error message when timeout occurs, but can't find how to do it without passing the `loginProgressBar` and `loginTimeoutErrorTextview` or other UI related variables. Basically keep the UI changes in the `Fragment`.

What i do in my `loginFragment` when pressing login

```
try {
    loginViewModel.login(
        binding.emailEditText.text.toString(),
        binding.passwordEditText.text.toString()
    )
} catch (e: IOException) { // THIS doesn't work
    binding.loginProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    binding.loginTimeoutErrorTextview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

From what i've found the timeout throws an `IOException` so everything is correct here

`loginViewModel.login` method:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    val securedLoginRequest = encodedRequest(username, password)

    Log.i("API Login", "Sent data: $securedLoginRequest")

    try {
        Log.i("API Login", "login started")
        // _response is a LiveData<String>
        _response.value =
            ApiServiceObject.retrofitService.postLogin(securedLoginRequest)

        Log.i("API Login", "Login successful, token = ${_response.value}")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw e // THIS should theoretically get catched by the block above right?
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.w("API Login", e.toString())
    }
}
```

Problem is the thrown exception in Block 2 doesn't get catched in Block 1

I've found a workaround by simply passing down `loginProgressBar` and `loginTimeoutErrorTextview` to `loginViewModel.login` but is that alright? Isn't there better ways?

UPD: some clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way, by using a `StateFlow` instead of `LiveData` in the `ViewModel` as follows:

```
private val _loginState = MutableStateFlow<LoginState>(LoginState.Empty)
val loginState = _loginState.asStateFlow()

sealed class LoginState {
    object Empty : LoginState()
    object Loading : LoginState()
    data class Success(val result: String) : LoginState()
    data class Error(val error: Throwable) : LoginState()
}
```

Then responding to it in the `Fragment` like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch{
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
        loginViewModel.loginState.collect { state ->
            binding.loginProgressBar.isGone = state !is LoginState.Loading

            when (state) {
                is LoginState.Error -> { doSomething() }
                is LoginState.Success -> { doSomething() }
                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `viewModelScope` is a `CoroutineScope`. And **Coroutine**  acts like a **Thread** (For more details about **Coroutine** you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021816/difference-between-a-thread-and-a-coroutine-in-kotlin)).

So you cannot have a outer try-catch like this:

```kotlin
try {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        ...
        throw IOException("Some IO Exception")
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    // It will never pass here and instead the program should crash above
    ...
}
```

The proper way to handle possible Exception within a **Coroutine** is to [have the try-catch inside it](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#handling-exceptions):

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    val securedLoginRequest = encodedRequest(username, password)

    Log.i("API Login", "Sent data: $securedLoginRequest")

    try {
        Log.i("API Login", "login started")
        // _response is a LiveData<String>
        _response.value =
            ApiServiceObject.retrofitService.postLogin(securedLoginRequest)

        Log.i("API Login", "Login successful, token = ${_response.value}")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        // You should either have a Callback to return this Exception outside this Coroutine, 
        //  or you should handle the UI update here
        // If you throw Exception here, your program should crash
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.w("API Login", e.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't really answer the question, as i wanted to do the UI changes in the `Fragment` to keep the UI and logic separate.
But still thanks for clarification.