# How to run suspend method via reflection?

Tags: java, kotlin, async-await, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

There is an coroutine block that can runs suspend functions.

But I call the function by `invoke` via reflection. This is java style invocation, apparently a simple call will not work.
Are there ways to run reflected method asynchronously? How to await this method?

```
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.*

class TestClass(val InString: String) {
    suspend fun printString() {
        println(InString)
    }
}

fun launch(context: CoroutineContext, block: suspend () -> Unit) =
        block.startCoroutine(StandaloneCoroutine(context))

private class StandaloneCoroutine(override val context: CoroutineContext): Continuation<Unit> {
    override fun resume(value: Unit) {}

    override fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable) {
        val currentThread = Thread.currentThread()
        currentThread.uncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(currentThread, exception)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch(EmptyCoroutineContext) {
        val a = TestClass("TestString");

        for (method in a.javaClass.methods) {
            if (method.name == "printString")
                method.invoke(a)  // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/calling-coroutines-suspend-functions-via-reflection/4672

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

Since Kotlin 1.3 reflection natively supports calling suspending functions via `KFunction.callSuspend` and `KFunction.callSuspendBy`, so the above workaround is no longer needed.

**Original Answer**

Every `suspend` method in Kotlin is represented on JVM via CPS transformation that is explained in the [coroutines design document](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#continuation-passing-style). Java reflection is not aware about it and Kotlin reflection does not currently provide convenient means to perform invocation of suspending function either.

You'll have to do invocation with CPS transformation yourself via helper function. I'd suggest to implement the following helper for this purpose:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.intrinsics.*

suspend fun Method.invokeSuspend(obj: Any, vararg args: Any?): Any? =
    suspendCoroutineOrReturn { cont ->
        invoke(obj, *args, cont)
    }
```

Now if you replace `invoke` with `invokeSuspend` in your code, then it is going to work just like expected.

Comment: Note: If you are using Kotlin 1.3, you should change `suspendCoroutineOrReturn` to `suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn`

Comment: note that the function `kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn` is not one intelliJ finds with auto-import: you have to import it manually, or fully qualify it as you type it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Kotlin reflection and call `suspend` as follows:

```
suspend fun Any.invokeSuspendFunction(methodName: String, vararg args: Any?): Any? =
        this::class.memberFunctions.find { it.name == methodName }?.also {
            it.isAccessible = true
            return it.callSuspend(this, *args)
        }
```