# How to invoke a kotlin method by reflection?

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

Here is my code:

```
class Repository {
    companion object {
        suspend fun clientList(clientListRequest: HashMap<String, String>): List<ClientEntity> {
            var result = NetConfig.api.clientList(clientListRequest).rows
            if (result == null) return emptyList()
            return result
        }
    }

}
```

Try to invoke:

```
     var method: Method? = null
     for (i in 0..Repository.javaClass.declaredMethods.size) {
         if (Repository.javaClass.declaredMethods[i].name.equals(methodName)) {
            method = Repository.javaClass.declaredMethods[i]
            log("${method}")
              break
            }
       }
     method?.isAccessible = true
```

The log prints:

> "public final java.lang.Object com.**.commonlib.net.Repository$Companion.clientList(java.util.HashMap,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
> "

As you can see, I don't declare a parameter which type is Continuation. I'm confused what is it and how to invoke the method?

Comment: As the function is a `suspend` one, the `Continuation` gets passed to it implicitly.

Comment: It might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47683449/1631967

Comment: It works for me! Thanks!

Comment: Good, you're welcome :)